# Asking about a company: do I use "who" or "what"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, questions

> Nike makes huge profits.

Should the question about the subject Nike be:

1. Who makes huge profits?
2. What makes huge profits?

Comment: How about "Which/What company makes a huge profit?"

Comment: What @Rathony said. *Who* sounds like a natural person. *What* sounds like importing cocaine.

Answer (score 3):

Use **who**, as a pronoun it means:

> what or which person or people.

So it doesn't just refer to a single individual, and a company is a group of people, so **who** is correct.

Were you to use "what" it would sound like you were asking about an export of the company, rather than the company itself, or that you had just completely misheard the speaker or that you had never heard of "Nike" before and didn't know what it was.

In the case of companies, generally use "who."

> Who are we?

Will commonly be seen on kickstarter campaigns for example, when a company introduces themselves. Not "what are we?"